# Error in reading SAS dataset in R 3.0.1

Tags: r

I am trying to read SAS dataset in R 3.0.1.

I have downloaded Hmisc package required to use sas.get function. But I am getting note as below:

```
Hmisc library by Frank E Harrell Jr
Type library(help='Hmisc'), ?Overview, or ?Hmisc.Overview')
to see overall documentation.
NOTE:Hmisc no longer redefines [.factor to drop unused levels when
subsetting.  To get the old behavior of Hmisc type dropUnusedLevels().
Attaching package: ‘Hmisc’
```

Then I am using the following command:

```
sas.get(library = "C:\\SAS_dataset", member = "test", formats = FALSE, sasprog = sasprog)
```

Then the R goes in infinite loop and does not give output. Finally when i press "Esc", it terminates by giving an warning message saying

```
Warning message:
running command '"C:/program files/SAS/SAS 9.1/sas.exe" "C:\Users\TEJASW~1.ABH\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpML87zC\SaS13c41642d38.3.sas" -log "_temp_.log"' had status 10708
```

I tried to find the reason for the same, but all in vain.

I don't understand the reason for this. Is it due to some note given by Hmisc package or something else?

Also I noted that I am facing this problem for latest version i.e. 3.0.1 only. Whereas I was able to read the SAS dataset with the same commands in version 2.15.1.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tejasweeni

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of SAS file formats, many of them poorly documented.  Are you sure you're reading in the right kind?

Comment: I am using .sas7bdat format. The strange thing is I am able to read the SAS dataset in 2.15.1 version but not in latest one i.e. 3.0.1.

Comment: See the answers to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006822/read-sas-sas7bdat-data-into-r/30043226#30043226

Answer (score 1):

If you have SAS, you can always export your data to a CSV file and read in R using read.table() or read.csv(). I think this is often the best solution.