# How to read large SAS data in R

Tags: r, sas

I have a sas7bdat data set of 2GB which i want to read in R. I am using sas7bdat package to read the dataset but after using read.sas7bdat,there is no response from R and it keeps on running for hours without any output.

I have tried using sas7bdat and haven package also.
Can anyone help me read the data in R quickly.

Comment: Have you seen this package - http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/03/04/haven-0-1-0/ ?

Comment: with ``haven`` the function is ``read_sas("file.sas7bdat")``

Answer (score 5):

Example

```
/* SAS */
libname rdata "C:/tmp";
data rdata.test; 
    input x y;
    datalines;
 5 6
 7 8
 ;
 run;

# R
setwd("C:/tmp")

# install.packages("haven")
library(haven)
test <- read_sas("test.sas7bdat")
```

The `read_sas` function in the `haven` package should be much faster than the `sas7bdat` package's functions. As per Hadley's [GitHub description](https://github.com/hadley/haven):

> Can read SAS's proprietary binary format (SAS7BDAT). The one other
>   package on CRAN that does that, sas7bdat, was created to document the
>   reverse-engineering effort. Thus its implementation is designed for
>   experimentation, rather than efficiency. Haven is significantly faster
>   and should also support a wider range of SAS files (including
>   compressed), and works with SAS7BCAT files.

Comment: "'The read_sas function is supposedly much quicker for the haven package." Source?

Comment: see their github. I've updated by post

Comment: Why not adding this in your post, rather as a comment?

Comment: I am getting the error message on using read_sas :  "Error: Failed to parse C:\Users\Desktop\new_clinical.sas7bdat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features."

Comment: what happens if you try loading the file without the extension. i.e. see [here](https://github.com/hadley/haven/issues/34)

Comment: I am still not able to read the file. Without extension it is giving error as : Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="D:\Biostatistics\Data\derived\clinical": The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @user3710546 see also my benchmarks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30043226/3576984