# Error when trying to import SAS7BDAT file

Tags: r, import, error-handling, sas, compression

I have a file in sas7bdat format thats 132mb large. I don't have SAS on my computer, i received this file from another statistician.

I try to import the sas7bdat file using the sas7bdat package and the `read.sas7bdat` function which has worked for me previously.

This is the import code:

```
biostat <- read.sas7bdat(file="/Users/Phil/Desktop/Work/Study/infwork.sas7bdat")
```

When I do this i receive this error

```
Error in read.sas7bdat(file="/Users/Phil/Desktop/Work/Study/infwork.sas7bdat") : 
  file contains compressed data
```

I haven't been able to figure out why i receive this error and according to some sources this can only be fixed in SAS using `compress=NO` or `compress=binary` to compress the file and then import it to R, the problem is I don't have SAS, is their a way around this problem?

All help i appreciated!

Comment: You need to give drive name, such as: "d://Users/Phil/Desktop/Work/Study/infwork.sas7bdat"

Comment: Download either SAS viewer or UE to convert file to a useable format. Or request data in a different format.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006822/read-sas-sas7bdat-data-into-r/30043226#30043226) question of mine; I can't recommend using `read.sas7bdat`.

Comment: Downloaded SAS JMP and saved the file as a CSV from the SAS program and subsequently imported it with "read.table".