# How to convert SAS's .SSD to .CSV?

Tags: sas

I'm having trouble converting .SSD files to .CSV. I first attempted this with SAS Universal Viewer, but that didn't work. Now I'm using SAS Studio On-Demand for Academics. The data I'm using are [from here](https://www.nhtsa.gov/file-downloads?p=nhtsa/downloads/NASS/1980/).

I uploaded two data files (ACCIDENT.SSD and VEHICLE.SSD) from that source to a folder called `NASS` in SAS Studio and attempted to define that folder as a new library. However, I'm getting hung up on the library creation step.

```
LIBNAME NASS v6 '/home/u59316558/sasuser.v94/NASS';
PROC EXPORT DATA=NASS.ACCIDENT
            OUTFILE="/home/u59316558/sasuser.v94/CARS.csv"
            dbms=csv replace;
```

which returns

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 68         
 69         LIBNAME nass v6 '/home/u59316558/sasuser.v94/NASS';
 ERROR: The V6 engine cannot be found.
 ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
 70         PROC EXPORT DATA=NASS.ACCIDENT
 71         OUTFILE="/home/u59316558/sasuser.v94/CARS.csv"
 72         dbms=csv replace;
 73         
 74         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 NOTE: Unable to open parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST in update mode. Temporary parameter values will be saved to 
 WORK.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST.
 ERROR: Libref NASS is not assigned. 
 ERROR: Export unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
 84
```

How can I convert these .SSD file to .CSV in SAS Studio or otherwise?

Comment: Remove the v6 from the libname and try that. I am unfamiliar with a .SSD extension with SAS. SAS datasets are normally .sas7bdat extension. However, the error is with the v6 so get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks @AlanC! That successfully creates a library called NASS, but it's empty. My understanding is that .SSD is from SAS v6 (https://csccsc.web.unc.edu/2016/06/what-are-ssd-and-sd2-files/), and the data are likely from 1980.

Comment: You cannot use Unix version of SAS to read version 6 dataset created under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tom. Is a local install of SAS on Windows my only option then?

Comment: I would use Stat/Transfer  https://manual.stattransfer.com/index.html?hs133.html

Comment: Wow. I started with SAS 5.18 so have obviously used that extension but I was on mainframes primarily back in the day. You may want to post the issue to SAS-L or SAS Community to find out if someone still has v6 around. SAS R&D/Tech Support probably has it available. Call SAS tech support and ask if they are willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Libname engine documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/hostwin/chloptfmain.htm), you likely *cannot* read these in directly, with any current version of SAS.  `.ssd` files are v603 or v604 datasets, and unfortunately x64 64-bit SAS does not have the ability to read these in whatsoever, barring reverse-engineering the file format.

As noted in Tom's comment, your best option is likely a third party such as Stat/Transfer or similar which might allow you to read it in, or failing that finding a 32-bit SAS installation - but that's likely difficult to do at this point.

Comment: You can read 6.12 or 6.04 .SSD files with PC SAS version 8, if you can find a working version somewhere.  Don't have to go all the way back to 1990's.  Just the 2000's.

Comment: @Tom I believe 9.4 can actually do it, just 32 bit, which will be hard to find...