# How to connect .SAS file in a network drive to Power BI

Tags: r, sas, powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect .SAS files to Power BI Desktop that sit on network drive.

I have tried the below steps

1. Installed R
2. Installed package sas7bdat
3. Tried the below snippet

```
require(sas7bdat)
input<-read.sas7bdat("Filepath&name.sas")
```

But I face the below error.

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: there are other packages to read sas files in R as well. e.g., `haven` is a good package ([usage](https://github.com/samkart/readwrite/blob/master/readwrite/R/readwrite.r)). Or, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006822/read-sas-sas7bdat-data-into-r) SO Q/A

Comment: Why would you try to read a program as if it was a dataset?  SAS will store the text of the program in the `.sas` file.  It would store data into a `.sas7bdat` file.

Comment: A .sas file is a text file with programs, it usually does not contain data at all.