# read.sas7bdat unable to read due to formats/labels number not matching

Tags: r, sas

A R rookie here. I was trying to read in a SAS dataset into Rstudio using read.sas7bdat but kept getting the following error message.

```r
> # Load the raw EDC data
> raw_bsln <- read.sas7bdat(paste0(raw_dat_dir, "bsln", ".sas7bdat"), debug = TRUE)
Error in read.sas7bdat(paste0(raw_dat_dir, "bsln", ".sas7bdat"), debug = TRUE) : 
  found 60 column formats and labels 59 expected please report bugs to maintainer
In addition: Warning message:
In read_bin(buf, off, len, "integer", ...) :
```

I was able to read in the previous version of this SAS dataset (i.e., the same metadata) into R, but for some reason it stopped working. Please advise. Thanks!

Tried google  but couldn't find anything that's helpful.

Comment: I don't know the reason for this error but have you tried `haven` package for reading sas and stata datasets. 

This may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006822/read-sas-sas7bdat-data-into-r

Comment: Thank you Golem. I was able to read in the dataset with read_SAS{haven}, but was really curious how this error would occur and if anyone had bumped into something similar.

Comment: Do you know what version of SAS was used to create that file?

Comment: It was a data extract created by an electronic data capturing system called Medidata.